# Uniform variable reported not found LWJGL 3

Tags: java, gradle, opengl, glsl, lwjgl

### Introduction

I'm creating a 2D OpenGL game in Java using the LWJGL 3 dependencies in Gradle.

Currently I have implemented a class VertexArray, which handles model data (`vertices`, `indices`, `texturecoords`) - including creating and handling the `VAOs` and `VBOs`.

I them implemented Shaders and can successfully load uniforms such as `mat4` for the projection and transformation matrix. I then added in textures using the `org.l33tlabs.twl PNGDecoder` and wrapped it all in a class `Texture`, that handles binding the texture unit, unbinding and deleting the texture from openGL. The bind function also calls `shader.setUniform1f("textureSampler",0);` before binding the texture.

### Code

`entityVertex.glsl`

```
#version 400 core

in vec4 position;
in vec2 textureCoords;

out vec2 passTextureCoords;

uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 transformationMatrix;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * transformationMatrix * position;
    passTextureCoords = textureCoords;
}
```

`entityFragment.glsl`
#version 400 core

```
in vec2 passTextureCoords;

out vec4 out_Color;

uniform sampler2D textureSampler;

void main()
{
    vec4 colour = texture(textureSampler,passTextureCoords);
    out_Color = colour;
}
```

`vertexArray render`

```
public void bind() {
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_ATTRIB);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(TCOORD_ATTRIB);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, tbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
}

public void unbind() {
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_ATTRIB);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(TCOORD_ATTRIB);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

public void draw() {
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, count, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
}

public void render(Shader shader, Texture texture) {
    texture.bind(shader);
    bind();
    draw();
    texture.unbind();
    unbind();
}
```

`texture`

```
public void bind(Shader shader) {
    shader.setUniform1f("textureSampler", 0); //<-- Line that throws error
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
}

public void unbind() {
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

### Problem

When I run this, I get the error `"Could not find uniform variable 'textureSampler'!"` from this method in the shader:

```
private Map<String, Integer> locationCache = new HashMap<>();

public int getUniform(String name) {
    if (locationCache.containsKey(name))
        return locationCache.get(name);
    int result = glGetUniformLocation(ID, name);
    if (result == 1) System.err.println("Could not find uniform variable '" + name + "'!");
    else locationCache.put(name, result);
    return result;
}

public void setUniform1f(String name, float value) {
    if (!enabled) start();
    glUniform1f(getUniform(name), value);
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/ritcat14/Spot/tree/submodules) is a link to the main Git repo, if you clone you will need to import and updade submodules (im making the same game in java awt and openGL)
[Here](https://github.com/ritcat14/SpotGL) is a link to the GL specific submodule

Any obvious issues? If you need to see more code please let me know.

Comment: It is a typo `if (result == 1)` -> `if (result == -1)` respectively `if (result < 0)`

Comment: Please post this as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`glGetUniformLocation`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGetUniformLocation.xhtml) returns -1 if the name is not the name of an active uniform variable in the specified program:

<s>`if (result == 1) System.err.println("Could not find uniform variable '" + name + "'!");`</s>

```java
if (result == -1) System.err.println("Could not find uniform variable '" + name + "'!");
```